# Sound stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04 after changing home directory

Tags: sound

This morning I had perfect sound on my PC. After confronting some issues (like setting my home folder on my HDD drive), sound had permanently turned to mute (I can't change it back), and my volume (+ and -) buttons don't work anymore.

Even when I'm trying to manually volume-up, it does nothing:

[image: photo]

When I return to this menu, it changes back to mute and 0% volume.

When I connect headphones the same thing happens.

Any suggestions?

edit:
recent action was moving my home folder to my HDD drive from the SSD..

[image: output for these commands:]

and thanks for answering Z-S and David Foerster

Comment: Could you please go into some more detail about what you were doing that seems to have caused the problem?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in 20.04 lts .The below fixed the problem for me

Permanent fix:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui then
Run hdajackretask and then
Parser hints > jack_detect = no
Apply now then and
Install boot override
```